# Split and use Time Object as Int in Swift

Tags: notifications, swift4

In swift I am using my DatePickerView to get some time inputs from user. I needed to convert it to local time and it works good.

The Code is :

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
    selectedMorningTime = dateFormatter.string(from: morningHour.date)
    selectedEveningTime = dateFormatter.string(from: eveningHour.date)
```

and the example output is "12:30"(this is GMT 3 format, if I try to convert it date It converts the example to "9:30".

My problem is that I need to use this time in Local Notifications but it only accepts dateComponents and dateComponents accept only ".hour" and ".minute" attributes.

```
dateComponentsForMorning.hour = 12
dateComponentsForMorning.minute = 30
```

How can I split my time as hour and minutes, so I can use it like this example:

```
dateComponentsForMorning.hour = convertedMorningHour
dateComponentsForMorning.minute = convertedMorningMinute
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar method dateComponents to get your time components from your date picker and use it to schedule your notification:

```
let morningHour = UIDatePicker()
let selectedMorningTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute], from: morningHour.date)
print("Hour:", selectedMorningTime.hour!, ", Minute:", selectedMorningTime.minute!)   // "Hour: 2 , Minute: 24\n"
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but the problem is that whenever I use date picker Date to add it, the time will be UTC 0, but I need the UTC of the user. dateComponents.timezone gives me UTC + 0 also. Only way I did the UTC + 3 was to do with dateFormatter.